# Not Loading proper Css on shared ip hosting server/ check images on server via ip

Tags: wordpress, ip, wordpress-theming, browser-cache, shared-hosting

i've uploaded a wordpress site on new server via shared ip. now makes changes in localhost which are working fine then uploaded that files (Css, php) on the server.
now the css is not working on server.(my css is in the themes of wordpress folder) every time browser(s) loading the pervious css which i've deleted already. i've flushed the DNS cache, cleared browsing history.
checking my site like this: as i don't have domain yet.

```
http://174.121.38.115/~username/
```

this is my hosting server ip.
Also told me how to check the images using ip whether they are properly placed and working or not????

Comment: I can't access the link you posted, it just redirects to a 404 page.

When you load the page, have you checked the CSS path the application is trying to load? Look for it in the Network tab of Chrome Inspector/Firebug.

Comment: @phil Many thanks buddy the actual link is the different user name and the website is loading css from the previous domain's server. So it mean when that domain is redirected to this IP then it will work fine???

Comment: That should be the case yep.  Assuming the domain is the same and the document root is setup correctly on the server side.  You can check that this would be the case by adding the following line to your hosts file: `174.121.38.115 www.dentistlivingston.com` and then accessing www.dentistlivingston.com in your browser.  Here's how to edit your hosts file: http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hosts-file/